# How can I get a list of indexed keys in Titan?

Tags: gremlin, titan

I am using Titan v0.3.1 and would like to see a list of which keys I have already indexed via `createKeyIndex`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you found for yourself you can use the Blueprints `getIndexedKeys(Vertex.class)` method for this, however the Titan type system has a lot more to offer than `createKeyIndex`.  The longer you work with Titan the more you will want to learn about the Type Maker system:

https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/wiki/Type-Definition-Overview

In that case the types returned by `getIndexedKeys` may not be enough.  Here's some Gremlin to get you more details:

```
gremlin> g = GraphOfTheGodsFactory.create('/tmp/titan')
13/08/28 16:28:23 INFO diskstorage.Backend: Configuring index [search] based on: 
...
13/08/28 16:28:25 INFO cluster.metadata: [Astaroth / Asteroth] [titan] update_mapping [vertex] (dynamic)
==>titangraph[local:/tmp/titan]
gremlin> import static com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.system.SystemKey.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.java.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.pipes.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.pipes.filter.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.pipes.sideeffect.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.pipes.transform.*
...
==>import static com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.system.SystemKey.*
gremlin> import com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.java.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.pipes.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.pipes.filter.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.pipes.sideeffect.*
==>import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.pipes.transform.*
...
==>import com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.types.*
gremlin> g.newTransaction().getVertices(TypeClass, TitanTypeClass.KEY).collect{[it.name,it.dataType]}
==>[reason, class java.lang.String]
==>[name, class java.lang.String]
==>[type, class java.lang.String]
==>[time, class java.lang.Integer]
==>[place, class com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.attribute.Geoshape]
==>[age, class java.lang.Integer]
```

You might want to look at the Titan API for more information on the `TitanKey` that is returned from that call to `getVertices` (as types are stored as vertices):

http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/0.3.2/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanKey.html

Comment: This is great, thanks @stephen-mallette.  You're right about Titan's other types: I have already been exploring the ElasticSearch integration with Titan for more advanced indexes & searching.

Answer (score 5):

In the Gremlin shell, you can use Blueprints' [KeyIndexableGraph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Graph-Indices#keyindexablegraph-and-fast-lookup-of-elements-by-keyvalue-pairs) `getIndexedKeys` function:

```
gremlin> g.getIndexedKeys(Vertex.class)
==>my_key_1
==>my_key_2
==>my_key_3
```

(`my_key_1`, `my_key_2`, and `my_key_3` are the 3 indexed vertex keys)

To grab the indexes for keys on edges, use `Edge.class` in place of `Vertex.class` above.