# How can I get a list of indexed keys in Janusgraph?

Tags: janusgraph

In Titan, I could get a list of indexed key using this stackoverflow post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18497954/1647476. We switched to using Janusgraph 0.2.0. Does anyone know how can I get a list of indexed keys in Janusgraph?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a Gremlin console

```
mgmt = graph.openManagement()
mgmt.getGraphIndexes(Vertex.class)
```

It will return a list of index names. If you want to know which field keys are associated to a particular index:

```
mgmt.getGraphIndex('my_index_name').getFieldKeys()
```

Please visit [this gist](https://gist.github.com/robertdale/ad4c63910009dd1118abe67b33ce41e1) for details about schema description